# vim search result minimap and vim minimap bug

Tags: terminal

I have installed minimap on my vim 8.2, it is quite good, but i found bug in it.

1. Is there a "minimap" that can display search result on it too ? something like kate, when i do a search on kate; even if there are multiples of search result, kate will put red lines on the minimap indicating the location; so that we know where they are. This will be really helpful.
2. Bug of minimap. (GitHub - wfxr/minimap.vim ) I am using manjaro kDE Plasma.
   I have a long document, 44426lines.. (it will get longer still).
   I have found out that it stop at around line 43200  and refuse to go down anymore (even when i got so many more lines underneath cursor.
   That means: when i scrolling (ctrl+e or ctrl+y, or mouse scroll wheel) between line 44426 and line 43200, the mini map does not move , not even a bit.

I have tried to turn minimap on and off, that but does not solve the problem.
I tried quite and restart vim.. nothing works.

Comment: This may be best discussed with the plugin maintainers

Comment: @D.BenKnoble any recommendation for the search ? Thx